# Deploy com Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, capistrano

Tenho que rodar minha app rails em uma maquina e o SGBD (no caso o PostgreSQL) em outro servidor.

Configurei o `database.yml` da seguinte maneira:

```
production:
<<: *default
database: nomedobanco
username: username
password: senha
host: banco.cloudapp.net[poderia aqui colocar ip interno?]
```

E o desploy.rb:

```
server "app.cloudapp.net", :web, :app
server "banco.cloudapp.net", :db,primary:true
```

Quando faço *deploy* ocorre erro:

> [out :: appreviews.cloudapp.net] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extensio

Porque esse erro?

Comment: Você já tem o postgre instalado na máquina?

Comment: Edite tua pergunta adicionando mais informações. Por exemplo: qual sistema operacional tu está usando? Pode colocar o erro completo?

Comment: Você pode colocar IP interno se estiver na mesma rede o db e o app, tanto é q no development o padrão é localhost

Comment: Porque no seu `Gemfile` tem alguma `gem` que utiliza bibliotecas compartilhadas que não estão presentes ou não são encontradas no momento que o `Rubygems` é invocado para instalar as dependências. Se você postar o backtrace do erro além das informações já solicitadas nos comentários fica bem mais fácil de tentarmos te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas gems precisam ser compiladas localmente junto com bibliotecas nativas. A mensagem de erro está dizendo que uma dessas gems não foi instalada corretamente lá no seu servidor de deploy.

O deploy do capistrano tem uma etapa em que ele executa `bundle install` e é quando ele instala gems novas que você adicionou no Gemfile. Esta etapa deu erro.

Minha sugestão. Faça login no seu servidor e tente executar `bundle install` lá para ver o erro. Ou se você ja tiver o erro poste aqui.

Normalmente esses erros ocorrem porque falta alguma biblioteca em sua maquina de deploy. Se você analisar a mensagem de erro deve descobrir. Então basta usar `sudo apt-get install` para instalar (se for linux, mas estou assumindo que é)